# Reference a parent struct's field

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How can I make a child struct have a reference to one of it's parents fields?

**Example:**

```rust
pub struct Parent<'a> {
    s: String,
    child: Child<'a>,
}

pub struct Child<'a> {
    s: &'a String,
}
```

How do I get `Child.s` to point to `Parent.s` without triggering the borrow checker?

```rust
let s = String::new();

let child = Child {
    s: &s
};

let parent = Parent {
    child,
    s,
};
```

This code triggers the following error since it's borrowed by child when trying to move to parent:

`cannot move out of 's' because it is borrowed`

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use some kind of smart pointer, [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#) would do:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct Parent {
    s: Rc<String>,
    child: Child,
}

pub struct Child {
    s: Rc<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let s = Rc::new(String::new());

    let child = Child { s: s.clone() };

    let parent = Parent { child, s };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=819b8a3fc3562d4a35e1249f1fb26c8d)

In case it also needs to be mutable, check the docs on [Sharable mutable containers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html)

Comment: I need it to be editable, I know that I can use `RefCell` for that but then I lose some borrow checking

Comment: @Mendy, `Rc<RefCell>` then. It is well explained in the [docst](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html)

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment I know about that, but I don't wanna loose compile time borrow checking

Comment: @Mendy, yeah, I understand. But that is the way it is :( Otherwise you will have to deal with raw pointers and `unsafe` terrain. Even more when dealing with mutable stuff.